# Deletion of module columns/attribute not visible on a given View

Tags: ibm-doors

I have been given the task of creating a DXL script. First problem is that I have never used DXL before, even though I have many years experience with DOORS itself. I have been surfing the Net to seek guidance on my particular problem. I also have a few specimen DXL scripts for reference.

My new client requires that for each View of a given Module, of which there are many Views, new "reduced" Modules are to be produced reflecting each View.

By "reduced", I mean that these new Modules are to contain nothing that isn't actually needed for that View., i.e. Columns, Attributes etc. These new Modules will only have the single View.

So, the way forward as I see it, is to take copies of the single master Module, one for each View, rename those copies to reflect a given Master Module/Required View, select that required View in the given copy Module and then delete everything that is not needed by that View, i.e. available Columns, Attributes etc.

This would be simple if I had the required DXL knowledge, which I am endeavouring to pick up as fast as I can.

If at all possible, this script has to be generic and be able to work upon any of the master Module copies to produce the associated "reduced" Module reflecting a particular View.

The client aims to use the script periodically for View archiving (I know, that's the way they want it).

### Clarification

Some clarification of what I believe is required, given the following text from my original question:

> If at all possible, this script has to be generic and be able to work upon any of the master Module copies to produce the associated "reduced" Module reflecting a particular View.

So, say there are ten views of the master Module, outside of the DXL script, I would copy the master Module ten times, renaming each copy to reflect each of the ten views. Unless you know different, each of those ten copies will reflect the same “Absolute Number”s as are in the master Module, so no problem there?

So, starting with the first of the copied Modules, each named to reflect the View it will eventually represent, its View would be set from the ten Views available to it, that which matches its title.

The single generic DXL script would then be run against that first copy Module, the aim being to delete everything not actually needed for that view, i.e. Attributes, Columns etc. Would some kind of purging command be required in the script for any aforementioned deleted items?

The single generic DXL script would then delete ALL views from that copy Module. The log that is produced when running the script also needs capturing, but I’m not sure whether this should be done from within the script, if possible or as a separate manual task outside of the script.

The aforementioned (indented) process would then be repeated, using the same generic script, against the remaining nine copied Modules. The intension is to leave us with ten copy Modules, each one reflecting one of the ten possible Views, with each one containing only the Attributes, Columns etc. required for that View.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a mirror of a module with this approach is not so easy IMO. Think e.g. about "Absolute Number". If the original module contains the numbers 15 (level 1), 2000 (level 2), 1 (level 1), you will have to create 2000 objects, purge 1997 of them and move them to the correct place. 
There is a "duplicate" tool at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=43862118-113d-4eac-b3f1-21d3b73959d1 which tries to do this, but as stated there, this script is said not to work correctly in all situations.

So, I would rather use the approach "string clipCopy (Item i); string clipPaste(Folder folderRef)". Should be faster and less error prone. But: all Out-Links will also be copied with this method, you will probably have to delete these after the copy or else the link target module(s) will have lots of In-Links.

The problem is still not so easy to solve, as every view might have DXL columns that rely on some or other attribute, and it might contain DXL attributes which again might rely on sth else. I doubt that there is a way to analyze DXL code "on the fly" and find out which columns may be deleted.

Perhaps a totally different approach would be feasible: open each view and create an export to Excel, this way you will get rid of any dynamic dependencies. Then re-import the excel sheet to a new DOORS module. You will still have the "Absolute Number" problem, but perhaps you can make a deal that you will have a pseudo attribute "Original Absolute Number" and disregard the "new" "Absolute Number"'

Quite a big task for a DXL beginner....

Update: On second thought, perhaps you might want to combine these approaches

- agree with your employer that you will use an alternative attribute for Absolute Number
- use a loop like Russel suggested, when creating objects remember that objects might have to be created "below" or "after" its predecessor or sibling
- for DXL attributes do not copy the DXL code but the actual current value of the object
- for DXL columns create pseudo attributes _ and create a new view that uses these pseudo attributes instead of the original value

Comment: Clarification added to original post.

Comment: Robert, yes, that is more or less the task as I understood it.
To summarize: you have two ways of achieving this. Either use the clipboard to copy/paste the module to a new place and in the copy, delete everything that is not necessary or that disturbs (out links), or re-build the modules from scratch omitting everything that need not be in the copies. 
In both approaches you will have the difficulty of finding what is not needed, given that views can contain dynamic (i.e. calculated by DXL) values.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest approach is to copy the module using the clipboard x times (once for each view) and in each copy ONLY delete the "other" views and the out links, delete NOTHING ELSE.
This way you will at least have a slight chance of not deleting too much. But you have no advantage against the original module.

If your overall task is to create immutable versions of your module, you would be better off with a report or an export to Excel. IMHO, the requirement is not feasible without further decisions about the details. What is the overall goal, what shall be done with these copies?

Comment: With regard to the first half of your first paragraph, i.e. "...delete everything that is not necessary or that disturbs (out links)...", from within the script how do I ascertain everything that is not necessary for a particular view. That to me seems to be the main crux of the problem, i.e. locate each such item and then delete each located item.

Comment: @Robert, yes, I also see this as the main problem. I do not see any solution for such a task. You would have the same problem in Excel where you are asked to delete the content of a certain cell, but you can never know whether this content is used in some formula somewhere in the worksheet, the workbook, a macro or even in another workbook on some network share. You can only guess. And chances are high that your guess is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the entire module, then deleting everything not in that view, seems worse than just copying the things you need from each particular view.

I would take the following as the outline of your program:

```
for view in main module do {
    for column in view do {
        Find attribute for each column and store (possibly in a skip list?)
        Store name of column
    }
    create new module
    create needed types / attributes in new module
    create new view in new module

    for object in main module {
        create object in new module
        for attribute in main module {
            check if attribute is in new module {
                copy info from old object to new
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Each of these for X in y loops should be in the DXL reference manual in some for or another.

If you need more help, let me know!

Comment: Clarification added to original post.